# Php blocking on variable declaration (w/psql)

Tags: php, postgresql, variables, insert

I'm kind of a newbie in PHP but even I think this is not normal.

My code blocks in the followoing line all the time:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ('.$nick.', '.$data_format.', '.$custo.', '.$dest_origem.', '.$dest_destino.', NULL, '.$matricula.');';
```

I tried with double quotes and with the variables inside those double quotes and nothing.

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried `$insert="insert into boleia values($nick,$data_format.....)`??

Comment: @ganeshrj Wouldn't that give him exactly the same?

Comment: No, I think he missing quote some where. Its simple to use it without all the quotes and it still works!

Comment: @ganeshrj You haven't put any quotes in your example. It will probably fail if any of the values are strings.

Comment: @JonStirling I have tried using it with strings, I has worked for me.

Comment: Please read http://bobby-tables.com/ , http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP code is syntactically correct but the generated SQL is not because you are not using quotes to delimit the values.

You can do this:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ("'.$nick.'", "'.$data_format.'", "'.$custo.'", "'.$dest_origem.'", "'.$dest_destino.'", NULL, "'.$matricula.'");';
```

or this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ('".$nick."', '".$data_format."', '".$custo."', '".$dest_origem."', '".$dest_destino."', NULL, '".$matricula."');';
```

you can also do this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ('$nick', '$data_format', '$custo', '$dest_origem', '$dest_destino', NULL, '$matricula');";
```

but **none** of that ways are recommended because you are vulnerable to **SQL Injections**!

### How to prevent SQL Injections?

To prevent that you must escape the values using the appropriate function for your DB, for example, since you are using PostgreSQL you must use [pg_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) for every value:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ("'.pg_escape_string($nick).'", "'.pg_escape_string($data_format).'", "'.pg_escape_string($custo).'", "'.pg_escape_string($dest_origem).'", "'.pg_escape_string($dest_destino).'", NULL, "'.pg_escape_string($matricula).'");';
```

An other way would be using [pg_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) with [pg_execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php)

```
pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_insert", 'INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, NULL, $6);');
pg_execute($dbconn, "my_insert", array($nick, $data_format, $custo, $dest_origem, $dest_destino, $matricula));
```

Or even using [pg_query_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php)

```
pg_query_params($dbconn, 'INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, NULL, $6);',
                array($nick, $data_format, $custo, $dest_origem, $dest_destino, $matricula));
```

Comment: First off, there's no guarantee he's not escaping the values previous to the example code. Second, looks like OP is using PostgreSQL ;)

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you, I know that there's no guarantee but there's a possibility that he's not escaping, since SQL Injections are critical I wanted to show him a prevention in case he's not escaping. I didn't see the pgsql tag, I changed to PostgreeSQL equivalent methods.

Comment: Thankyou for actually discussing SQL injection. Good links for this are: http://bobby-tables.com , http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: It is also a good practice to specify the fields list `INSERT INTO boleia (field1, field2, ... ) VALUES ...`

Answer (score 0):

Each value in an insert query requires quotes around it unless it's a number or NULL.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ('$nick', '$data_format', '$custo', '$dest_origem', '$dest_destino', NULL, '$matricula');";
```

If you use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you don't have to worry about quoting or escaping anything.

Example from this [PDO Tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3)");
$stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $field1, ':field2' => $field2, ':field3' => $field3));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: Note that the first approach is dangerously insecure and should be avoided. See http://bobby-tables.com , http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: It's only insecure if the variables come from user input or can be tampered with. You can't see that in the question. My answer points to an example of a parameterised query which is better than escaping anyway.

Comment: That's why I didn't downvote. It's always best to assume all input is unsafe, though, especially since you can perform XSS-like attacks to perform injection indirectly - get the bad data into the DB where a badly written program reads it out again and uses it in string interpolation. Think malicious username. It's not "from the user" to the author of the 2nd program, but from the DB; nonetheless, it remains unsafe if the user originally picked it and if it wasn't carefully validated.

Comment: @CraigRinger, why dont you post YOUR answer then? I wonder if you could do better ))) and we will vote )))

Answer (score -1):

You need to encapsulate the string values going in to the query.

E.g.

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ("'.$nick.'", "'.$data_format.'", "'.$custo.'", etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work neither. 

I'm thinking it might be something related with the variable's names. I'm not seeing anything else!
I'm running this with an echo before and another after and the one after this line never gets printed.

Comment: In that case, check your server logs. Both apache and postgres to find what the error is.

Comment: -1 because this is WRONG and **dangerously, critically insecure**. See http://bobby-tables.com , http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @CraigRinger You are making lots of assumptions about the OPs code beyond what we have been given. 

You are assuming that there is either no value checking / cleaning of the variables and probably assuming that the data is coming from user input.

While use of a decent abstraction layer like PDO with parameterised queries is the way to go, the example I gave is neither wrong, nor dangerous within the limited context of the question, though I will agree that used wrongly it will open up a huge hole and, as you have done, should be steered away from.

Comment: @JonStirling I'm not assuming the code that uses this unsafe (though that's a pretty safe bet, really): I'm saying that it's in my view not acceptable to assume that values are quoted and checked and rely on that. Sufficiently so that I wanted to make really sure to highlight the best answer. José's answer is a great example of how this can be covered well. In any case, a downvote is only -2 rep and it's -1 for me; is it really worth that much fuss? This is why people don't comment to explain when they downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You better use double quotes for the SQL strings as it will be easier for you later on to sport where you didn't encapsulate by the quotes your strings

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ('$nick', '$data_format', '$custo', '$dest_origem', '$dest_destino', NULL, '$matricula')";
```

Comment: I think this will work. If this doesnt work try with out all the single qoutes.

Comment: -1 because you should never be advising people to do string interpolation into SQL strings, especially without discussing the supplied-value quoting and security issues. Little bobby tables and mr `O'Brien` will be displeased with you. See http://bobby-tables.com , http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: so tell me the difference that would matter to the SQL if in PHP we construct it with the use of single quotes that the unexperiences user is having trouble to understand or the double quotes that make it slightly easier by eye to work with. for SQL it won't matter the quotes you would be use. Here we are constructing the string, this is a purely PHP-syntaxing issue - contructing the string using double quotes is easier when there are single quotes are present.

Comment: @MAXIM This is a question about *sql* and *databases* too though; my point is that we should *never* be advising people to interpolate SQL strings, even if it's convenient.

Comment: You need to be fair and read things more carefuly. Question was *WHY DOESNT WORK?*. My answer was *use this quotes and not these quotes to avoid the problem*. Thats it. It has nothing to do with sql injection or advising people wrong developing habits. Was I supposed to start a whole new PDO object and write here a 10 lines code for solving a syntax issue? So, if you want to realy object this, just add a comment or edit my aswer instead of judjing negatively. Thats my point

Answer (score -1):

People, common. The original question is only 1 (ONE) line long! It is exactly this:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ('.$nick.', '.$data_format.', '.$custo.', '.$dest_origem.', '.$dest_destino.', NULL, '.$matricula.');';
```

we don't have to fix here any non-escaped strings presuming he hasn't done it before, neither we should presume that he is using PostgreSQL just because we see it in the tags. He had a simple error - missing encapsulation of strings in the query. It is fixed, in it's simplest form, as this:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO boleia VALUES (\''.$nick.'\', \''.$data_format.'\', \''.$custo.'\', \''.$dest_origem.'\', \''.$dest_destino.'\', NULL, \''.$matricula.'\');';
```

And that's it!
If, and only if, we like to add some extra info, as of how to escape the strings in case this hasn't been done, or if we are better using double quotes since it is less human-error-prone in such case, or if there is a good PDO Tutorial to read.... it's all either an *additional info* after the exact answer to his problem, or a chatty-off-topic.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks!I ended up finding the problem on my own, but that (encapsulation of strings) was the problem. 

Thanks!
(and for the curious: I didn't had escaped the strings. Fixed, btw. Thnks)

Answer (score -2):

```
$db = new mysqli( some db data );

$nick = $db->real_escape_string( $nick );
$data_format = $db->real_escape_string( $data_format ); // this is probably not needed
$dest_origem = $db->real_escape_string( $dest_origem );
$dest_destino = $db->real_escape_string( $dest_destino );
$matricula = $db->real_escape_string( $matricula );

$insert = "INSERT INTO boleia VALUES ('$nick', '$data_format', '$custo', '$dest_origem', '$dest_destino', NULL, '$matricula')";
```

and you should be OK

Comment: This user is using PostgreSQL not MySQL, and that's a poor approach anyway; you should be using parameterized statements.